# Sicstus Prolog - How to build a tree from a list

Tags: tree, prolog

Got a problem about how to build a tree from a list.

Example: I've got `List = [1,2,3,4]`  and after running I want to get an answer like this

```
T = Tree(1, Tree(2, Tree(3, 4)).
```

I'm new to Sicstus. I've tried using code:

```
build_tree([X], X).
build_tree([H|S], T) :- build_tree([S] , Tree(H, T)).
```

It works when there's only one element in the list, but when there're more than 1 element in the list,
I get error code:

> Resource error: insufficient memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Kaarel noted, the degenerate form of a binary tree that you get when the nodes are inserted in sequence is a linked list:

[image: degenerate tree]

Prolog's list notation is simply syntactic sugar for a normal prolog term: `./2`, where the 1st argument is the head of the list and the 2nd the tail of the list. The sigil for the empty list is the atom '[]'. So, the internal representation of a list like `[1,2,3]` is the structure/term

```
.( 1 , .( 2 , .( 3 , '[]' )
```

A one element list, `[1]` as

```
.( 1 , '[]' )
```

And the empty list as the atom `'[]'`.

You can see the attraction of the syntactic sugar.

See http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node78.html for more details.

Given that identity, something like this will give you what your original post says you want:

```
list2tree( [X,Y] , tree(X,Y) )
  .
list2tree( [X|Xs] , tree( X , Ts ) :-
  list2tree( Xs , Ts )
  .
```

Though all you're doing is changing the functor. However, your structure doesn't seem to allow for the empty list/tree. How do you intend to represent that?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that uppercase symbols are usually reserved for variables (ISO prolog).
Here my solution:

```
build_tree([X,Y],'Tree'(X,Y)) :- !.
build_tree([X|Y],'Tree'(X,Z)) :- build_tree(Y, Z).
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything, a list **is** a tree, e.g.:

```
?- write_canonical([1, 2, 3, 4]).
'.'(1,'.'(2,'.'(3,'.'(4,[]))))
true.
```